# How to set dynamic data?

Tags: angular

https://plnkr.co/edit/7hOOoJNYvx4K91yKWqYj?p=preview

I have this plunker that is not working. When i do this then is working:

```
  data = { Alice: {}, Bob: {}}

<div *ngFor="let person of people">
  <h1>{{person}}</h1>
  <div>
    Material
    <select [(ngModel)]="data[person].material" (ngModelChange)="materialChange($event, person)">
      <option *ngFor="let material of materials" [value]="material">{{material}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    Colours
    <select [(ngModel)]="data[person].chosenColour">
      <option *ngFor="let colour of data[person].colours" [value]="colour">{{colour}}</option>
    </select>
  </di
```

How can i rewrite this because i need dynamic data, because i dont know how much data that i will have.. i dont need fixed value. Any suggestion?

Comment: i dont know what did i get downvote if i have example and clean question about my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I am understanding that instead of

```
data = { Alice: {}, Bob: {}}
```

your `people` array length is n

```
people = ['Alice', 'Bob']
```

and you want it to reflect the `data` object.

So what you can do, is to map the `people` array and insert each string value as a property of your object, which itself holds an empty object:

```
this.people.map(x => this.data[x] = {})
```

This way data will now based on your example look like the hard coded `data` in your **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3HY8brcJTTRYZ9pDDjjy?p=preview)**.